# Ubuntu 2022.04: How to upgrade Java from 17.0.4 to 17.0.5?

Tags: upgrade, java

I know this is a minor upgrade, and not in stable but I need the minor upgrade for some updated code to run.

1. How do I find what versions of a package are available?
2. How do I get the newer Java version when it's not in stable?

My current system shows:

```
% java -version
openjdk version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19
```

Many thanks.

Comment: First step is working out what OS/release you're using (*you've not told us so we can't help there*), then ensure you've got updated packages available to you (ie. *check your sources & ensure there are no warnings you've ignored*).  As Ubuntu is a *stable release* system, it maybe available if you move to a later release (*again we can't know not knowing your product details*) or the addition of 3rd party repositories (*again we can't help not knowing your basic OS/release details*)...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.